# h2o GLM GridSearch lambda value

Tags: python, glm, h2o

I am using H2O (Python) where I am playing with `H2OGridSearch` for alpha values of a GLM (`H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator`), also using `lambda_search=True` using k-fold cross-validation.

How can I get the best model's lambda value?

**EDIT**: Fully reproducible example

Data:

```
34.40 17:1 73:1 127:1 265:1 912:1 1162:1 1512:1 1556:1 1632:1 1738:1
205.10 127:1 138:1 338:1 347:1 883:1 912:1 1120:1 1122:1 1512:1
7.75 66:1 127:1 347:1 602:1 1422:1 1512:1 1535:1 1738:1
8.85 127:1 608:1 906:1 979:1 1077:1 1512:1 1738:1
51.80 127:1 347:1 608:1 766:1 912:1 928:1 952:1 1034:1 1512:1 1610:1 1738:1
110.00 127:1 229:1 347:1 602:1 608:1 1171:1 1512:1 1718:1
8.90 66:1 127:1 205:1 347:1 490:1 589:1 912:1 1016:1 1512:1
```

Call this file `h2o_example.svmlight`

Then run:

```
h2o_data = h2o.import_file("h2o_example.svmlight")
cols = h2o_data.columns[1:]
hyper_parameters = {"alpha": [0.0, 0.01, 0.99, 1.0]}
grid = H2OGridSearch(H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="gamma", link="log", lambda_search=True, nfolds=2, intercept=True, standardize=False),
hyper_params=hyper_parameters)
grid.train(y="C1", x=cols, training_frame=h2o_data)
grid_table = grid.get_grid(sort_by="r2", decreasing=True)
best = grid_table.models[0]
best.actual_params["lambda"]
best.actual_params["alpha"]
```

The last two commands fail, giving me an error:

```
TypeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Apparently, I am using `lambda_search` in a wrong way. How can I get a single alpha and lambda value for the best model according to my criterion?

Comment: Just to point out why your code does not work.  actual_params  "lambda_" and "alpha" refer to the parmeters the model was given in the first place - if they were fixed in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Final EDIT**

There are multiple ways of getting lambda (shown below) but here are two concise ways of getting lambda.(Note fully reproducible code is at the bottom)

If you have `lambda_search = True`, you can look at the model summary table under the `lambda_search` column and see what value is set for `lambda.min`, which is your best lambda

```
model.summary()['lambda_search']
```

which will produce a list with a string similar to:

```
['nlambda = 100, lambda.max = 12.733, lambda.min = 0.05261, lambda.1se = -1.0']
```

if you don't use lambda search and don't set a lambda value (or do set it) you can also use the summary table

```
model.summary()['regularization']
```

output looks like:

```
['Elastic Net (alpha = 0.5, lambda = 0.01289 )']
```

**Other options:**

look at the actual parameters of the model:
`best.actual_params['lambda']`
`best.actual_params['alpha']`

where `best` was your best model in the grid search results

**First EDIT**

to get the best model you can do

```
grid_table = grid.get_grid(sort_by='r2', decreasing=True)
best = grid_table.models[0]
```

Then you can use:

```
best.actual_params['lambda']
```

**Fully reproducible example**

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
h2o.init()

# import the airlines dataset:
# This dataset is used to classify whether a flight will be delayed 'YES' or not "NO"
# original data can be found at http://www.transtats.bts.gov/
airlines= h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/airlines/allyears2k_headers.zip")

# convert columns to factors
airlines["Year"]= airlines["Year"].asfactor()
airlines["Month"]= airlines["Month"].asfactor()
airlines["DayOfWeek"] = airlines["DayOfWeek"].asfactor()
airlines["Cancelled"] = airlines["Cancelled"].asfactor()
airlines['FlightNum'] = airlines['FlightNum'].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = ["Origin", "Dest", "Year", "UniqueCarrier", "DayOfWeek", "Month", "Distance", "FlightNum"]
response = "IsDepDelayed"

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid= airlines.split_frame(ratios = [.8])

# try using the `lambda_` parameter:
# initialize your estimator
airlines_glm = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = 'binomial', lambda_ = .0001)

# then train your model
airlines_glm.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)

# print the auc for the validation data
print(airlines_glm.auc(valid=True))


# Example of values to grid over for `lambda`
# import Grid Search
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch

# select the values for lambda_ to grid over
hyper_params = {'lambda': [1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0]}

# this example uses cartesian grid search because the search space is small
# and we want to see the performance of all models. For a larger search space use
# random grid search instead: {'strategy': "RandomDiscrete"}
# initialize the glm estimator
airlines_glm_2 = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = 'binomial')

# build grid search with previously made GLM and hyperparameters
grid = H2OGridSearch(model = airlines_glm_2, hyper_params = hyper_params,
                     search_criteria = {'strategy': "Cartesian"})

# train using the grid
grid.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)

# sort the grid models by decreasing AUC
grid_table = grid.get_grid(sort_by = 'auc', decreasing = True)
print(grid_table)

best = grid_table.models[0]
print(best.actual_params['lambda'])
```

Comment: Getting the best model as described above gives an object that has actual_params (<property at 0x7fa349f62050>) but when trying to use the commands as you mention, I get the following error: `'property' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: updated answer think this should solve your problem now

Comment: Still getting the same error. `type(best)` yields `h2o.estimators.glm.H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator` and `type(best.actual_params)` is `property`

Comment: The first is the correct type: `best` should be an H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator, but type(best.actual_params) should be a dict. Can you try the fully reproducible example I added to see if/when your code deviates? also instead of `best = h2o.get_model(grid.sort_by('r2', increasing=False)['Model Id'][0])` can you use `best = grid.get_grid(sort_by = 'auc', decreasing = True).models[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, your example works great. I am using `lambda_search=True` and explicitly providing alpha values. I have updated my question with a reproducible example (svmlight file) where you should hopefully get the same error.

Comment: When I try to run your example using alpha hyper-parameters and `lambda_search=True`, the `actual_params['lambda']` returns the full set of lambda values.

Comment: okay np! updated response. in your case try `best.summary()['lambda_search']` and look at `lambda.min`. hope this does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the following does not work

```
best = grid_table.models[0]
best.actual_params["lambda"]
best.actual_params["alpha"]
```

It may be an issue with h2o, but if you change the above to the following you should be able to at least access those parameters:

```
best = grid.models[x]
best.actual_params["lambda"]
best.actual_params["alpha"]
```

Note that I have changed `0` to `x` because you need to take note of which model performs the best according to your error criteria because the contents within `grid` may not be sorted according to your error criteria. This requires you to take a look at `grid_table`and take note of the model_id and looking at how the models are being stored in `grid`

Then you should be able to at least reference `lambda` and `alpha`. However, when you run a grid search on alpha and you turn the search on for `lambda` through the `lambda_search` property `best.actual_params["lambda"]` will return the full list of lambdas that were searched over. You could still reference it by considering what Lauren has suggested, but I typically like to see everything in a table and would suggest turning `lambda_search` off and adding it to the hyper parameters you search over.

```
import numpy as np
lambda_search_range = list(np.linspace(0,1,100))
h2o_data = h2o.import_file("h2o_example.svmlight")
cols = h2o_data.columns[1:]
hyper_parameters = {"alpha": [0.0, 0.01, 0.99, 1.0], 
"lambda": lambda_search_range}
grid = H2OGridSearch(H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="gamma", 
        link="log", lambda_search=False, nfolds=2, 
        intercept=True, standardize=False), hyper_params=hyper_parameters)
grid.train(y="C1", x=cols, training_frame=h2o_data)
grid_table = grid.get_grid(sort_by="r2", decreasing=True)
param_dict = grid_table.get_hyperparams_dict(grid_table.model_ids[0])
```

`param_dict` should be a dictionary that contains the alpha and lambda values for your best model according to the error criteria you specified.